# Changing the "Plugin Activated" Message Default

Tags: plugins, admin, hooks

Whenever an administrator in WordPress activates a plugin, upon the reload of the plugin page, a notice will appear upon successful activation reporting "Plugin Activated".

[image: Screenshot of Plugin Activated message]

Is there a way to change this text that appears inside the admin notice, or must I use my own custom message? Additionally, if I must use a custom message, will this suppress the default "Plugin Activated" message?

**Related Questions:**

- [Uninstall, Activate, Deactivate a plugin: typical features & how-to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to)
- [How to show custom message once on plugin activation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/how-to-show-custom-message-once-on-plugin-activation)
- [What's the point on gettext syntax?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/whats-the-point-on-gettext-syntax)

**Duplicate:**

Thanks to Pieter for the find:

- [How to Remove the Default "Plugin Activated" in WordPress"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14095642/1908141)

**Additional Resources:**

- [gettext()
  Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)

> ## **Note**
>
> Rememember that although 'gettext' filter is only applied during calls to the `translate()` function, `translate()` is used by virtually all other i18n functions in *[i18n.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/l10n.php?rev=29711)*. These include all of the functions listed here in this post on "[Gettext Syntax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/whats-the-point-on-gettext-syntax)".

Comment: Go and have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14095642/1908141

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this:

```
is_admin() && add_filter( 'gettext', 
    function( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
    {
        $old = array(
            "Plugin <strong>activated</strong>.",
            "Selected plugins <strong>activated</strong>." 
        );

        $new = "Captain: The Core is stable and the Plugin is <strong>activated</strong> at full Warp speed";

        if ( in_array( $untranslated_text, $old, true ) )
            $translated_text = $new;

        return $translated_text;
     }
, 99, 3 );
```

to modify the message to your likings:

[image: translated]

**We can refine it further:**

If you only want to activate the filter on the `/wp-admins/plugins.php` page, you can use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'load-plugins.php',
    function(){
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'b2e_gettext', 99, 3 );
    }
);
```

with:

```
/**
 * Translate the "Plugin activated." string
 */
function b2e_gettext( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    $old = array(
        "Plugin <strong>activated</strong>.",
        "Selected plugins <strong>activated</strong>." 
    );

    $new = "Captain: The Core is stable and the Plugin is <strong>activated</strong> at full Warp speed";

    if ( in_array( $untranslated_text, $old, true ) )
        {
            $translated_text = $new;
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 99 );
        }
        return $translated_text;
}
```

where we remove the gettext filter callback as soon we have a match.

If we want to check the number of gettext calls made, before we match the correct string, we can use this:

```
/**
 * Debug gettext filter callback with counter
 */
function b2e_gettext_debug( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
        static $counter = 0;
        $counter++;

        $old = "Plugin <strong>activated</strong>.";
        $new = "Captain: The Core is stable and the Plugin is <strong>activated</strong> at full Warp speed";
        if ( $untranslated_text === $old )
        {
            $translated_text = $new;
            printf( 'counter: %d - ', $counter );
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ , 99 );
        }
        return $translated_text;
}
```

and I get `301` calls on my install:
[image: 301]

I can reduce it to only `10` calls:

[image: 10]

by adding the gettext filter within the `in_admin_header` hook, within the `load-plugins.php` hook:

```
add_action( 'load-plugins.php',
    function(){
        add_action( 'in_admin_header',
            function(){
                add_filter( 'gettext', 'b2e_gettext_debug', 99, 3 );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Notice that this will not count the gettext calls before the internal redirect used when the plugins are activated.

To activate our filter *after* the internal redirect we can check the GET parameters used when plugins are activated:

```
/**
 * Check if the GET parameters "activate" and "activate-multi" are set
 */
function b2e_is_activated()
{
    $return         = FALSE;
    $activate       = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'activate',       FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $activate_multi = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'activate-multi', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if( ! empty( $activate ) || ! empty( $activate_multi ) )
        $return = TRUE;

    return $return;
}
```

and use like this:

```
b2e_is_activated() && add_filter( 'gettext', 'b2e_gettext', 99, 3 );
```

in the previous code example.

Comment: You nailed it, the gettex function. Excellent move

Comment: Why did you chain together is_admin() and add_filter() with a logical && operator? Is there some sort of short-circuit evaluation going on where if the user is not an administrator, then add_filter won't run?

Comment: I only wanted to target the backend and not the frontend. I took the `is_admin()` backend check outside the filter so it wouldn't have to run multiple times. I updated the answer to target only the `/wp-admins/plugins.php` page.

Comment: Excellent answer! +1 and I'd +10 it for keeping an eye on performance with the `get_text` filter.

Comment: @birgire: I haven't been able to get this to work in recent versions of WordPress. I went searching through the WP 4.0 code recently and the only place the 'gettext' filter is applied is through the translate function in i18n.php. Did you use an earlier version of WP?

Comment: @gate_engineer aha - I guess you used the bulk select when activating. Then you have to use: `$old = "Selected plugins <strong>activated</strong>.";` instead of `$old = "Plugin <strong>activated</strong>.";`. It looks like I forgot to test the bulk activation. Please check my updated answer. Should work for WP 3.9 and 4.0.

Comment: I've been adapting your answer for OOP, but haven't been able to get it working properly without dumping it out into a separate classless file.

Comment: @birgire, would the same process apply for deactivation message replacement?

Comment: yes that should work in a similar way @blackhawk

Comment: Its changing text for every plugin... Can we do that on specific plugin activation?

Comment: The problem is the redirect. Check 'plugin' GET parameter? If not available maybe hook into check_admin_referer and target 'activate-plugin_' . $plugin to write an option that says it's been activated and then delete it again on plugins.php page load. Maybe the recently_activated option can help? Might be better served as a new question @Omer